# Fatal error after changing robot.txt setting

Tags: magento2, fatal-error

Working on Magento 2.1.8 and PHP 7.
I have changed in Admin Panel

> **Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> XMLSitemap -> Search Engine Submission Settings the value of "Enable Submission to Robots.txt" to
>   Yes.**

**Following error message I got:**

> Fatal error: Class Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject contains 1 abstract method
>   and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining
>   methods (IteratorAggregate::getIterator) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pferd\vendor\zendframework\zend-stdlib\src\ArrayObject.php
>   on line 22

*Following the beginning of file ArrayObject.php*

```
namespace Zend\Stdlib;

use ArrayAccess;
use Countable;
use IteratorAggregate;
use Serializable;


 **line 22** class ArrayObject implements IteratorAggregate, ArrayAccess, Serializable, Countable
```

How can I reverse the change? I have no access anymore to AdminPanel to reverse the change.
Thanks

Comment: When you got this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution: **To solve this problem, run following commands.**

1. Delete the var directory from your root directory
2. php bin/Magento setup:upgrade
3. php bin/Magento setup:static-content:deploy
4. php bin/Magento cache:clean
5. php bin/Magento cache:flush

**At the End stop apache and MySQL service and  restart both services again which fixed your problem and everything works perfectly then.**

Comment: @helmut999 - Happy to help , keep helping :)